# Not able to save the image to disk in linux using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to save images to disk using spring boot and angular, however there are no 
exceptions thrown in the below code nor any errors, but i cannot see image in the required folder

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ImageController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/postImages", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = 
                        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
        public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadPolicyDocument(@RequestParam("image") 
                                                          List<MultipartFile> multipartFile)
       {
        String OUT_PATH = "home\\krishnachaitanya\\Pictures\\testing\\";

    try {
        for(MultipartFile mf: multipartFile)
        {
            byte[] bytes = mf.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(OUT_PATH+ mf.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
```

Comment: Update Path With  String OUT_PATH = "\\home\\krishnachaitanya\\Pictures\\testing\\";

Comment: @harkeshkumar nope, it did not fix the issue

Comment: are you getting response code is 200 ok ? or any error apart from IOException since you are just catching IOException you might got some other exception that you are not able to see

Comment: can you share  your console log

Comment: @PanditBiradar I am recieving 200

Comment: its might be possible you don't have permission to write a file in that dir can you try some other dir

Comment: change your OUT_PATH to `/home/krishnachaitanya/Pictures/testing/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think the file is successfully written, but not in the place you would expect. '\' is not a path separator on Linux and the path you specify is relative, so the file is written in the applications working directory. The file is named: `home\krishnachaitanya\Pictures\testing\oryginalFileName`.

Change the `OUT_PATH` to "/home/krishnachaitanya/Pictures/testing/"

Answer (score 0):

The OUT_PATH looks very wrong for a linux system. have you tried to use "/" instead of "\\"